# How to open link in a new tab via shortcut in Chrome on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, web-browsing, web-browser

On Windows, I would just hold control, and click the 30 links on the page I wanted to open. How do I do this in Mac?

Comment: so you click 30 times and open 30 tabs ?

Comment: Holding CTRL just opens the right click menu. I need the shortcut to open up the link in a new tab...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It will still take 30 clicks, one for each link, but…

Remember that  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  on Mac is usually equivalent to  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  on Windows.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  Click will open a link in a new a tab behind the current one, if you click a link.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  Click will open the new tab & bring it to the front.

These are the default settings [iirc] but they can be changed in Prefs…

[image]

*Edit:*
Sorry, I only just realised you said Chrome.
It does follow the same behaviour, though I can't find anywhere to actually change it.

Comment: It must have been website specific, because I tried a number of guesses and nothing worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just checked in Crome (macOS Monterey 12.3): it works the same way there as in Safari (`⌘`+click). Thank you for the useful info!

Answer (score -3):

Click and drag the tab out of the top bar.

Comment: What are you talking about?